# Sample of movie plot summaries

Tags: data-request, film

I'm looking for datasets about cinema in the US. In particular, I need a **representative sample** (as much as this can exist) of

- Movies that were properly released and seen in theatres in the US
- Released between 1950 to today
- Plot summaries
- Country of production
- Year of release

I found this [great resource from IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/interfaces/), but I can't find the plot summaries and countries of production.

Is it possible to extract/scrape this data from Wikipedia/DBpedia/IMDB?

Comment: You could scrape this from wikipedia, of course, but it would be a bit hit and miss parsing it. wikidata.org includes some of this information, but not all of it: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q17738 Also http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ark/personas/ may help